# select features within buffer arcgis javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to use the arcgis javascript to create a buffer select. when I try to add the script to select the features within the buffer, nothing works, but when I remove the selection part of the script the buffer works. Can any one assist please. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  h3 { margin: 0 0 5px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #444; }
  .shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
  }
  #map{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  #feedback {
    background: #fff;
    color: #444;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: arial;
    height: 200px;
    left: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 40;
  }
  #note { font-size: 80%; font-weight: 700; padding: 0 0 10px 0; }
</style>

<script>var dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad: true };</script>
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/"></script>
<script>
  dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
  dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
  dojo.require("esri.map");
  dojo.require("esri.tasks.geometry");
  dojo.require("esri.tasks.query");
  dojo.require("esri.layers.FeatureLayer");

  // one global for persistent app variables
  var app = {};


  function init() {
    var basemap;
    app.map = new esri.Map("map", { 
      basemap: "streets",
      center: [-82.44, 28.3],
      zoom: 12,
      slider: false
    });

    var layer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer");  
    app.map.addLayer(layer);

    app.qtask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/0");

    app.map.addLayer(new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer({ "id": "Geodesic" }));
    app.map.addLayer(new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer({ "id": "Euclidean" }));

    dojo.connect(app.map, "onClick", createBuffers);

    app.gsvc = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer");
  }

  function createBuffers(e) {
    var line, twentyPixels, bufferEuclidean, bufferGeodesic, distance, unit;

    app.map.getLayer("Geodesic").clear();
    app.map.getLayer("Euclidean").clear();
    app.map.graphics.clear();
    app.map.infoWindow.hide();

    twentyPixels = (app.map.extent.getWidth() / app.map.width) * 20;
    line = new esri.geometry.Polyline(app.map.spatialReference);
    line.addPath([
      [e.mapPoint.x - twentyPixels, e.mapPoint.y - twentyPixels],
      [e.mapPoint.x + twentyPixels, e.mapPoint.y + twentyPixels]
    ]);

    app.map.graphics.add(
      new esri.Graphic(line, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol())
    );

    distance = 660;
    unit = esri.tasks.GeometryService.UNIT_FOOT;

    bufferEuclidean = new esri.tasks.BufferParameters();
    bufferEuclidean.geometries = [ line ];
    bufferEuclidean.distances = [ distance ];
    bufferEuclidean.unit = unit;
    bufferEuclidean.outSpatialReference = app.map.spatialReference;

    bufferGeodesic = new esri.tasks.BufferParameters();
    bufferGeodesic.geometries = [ line ];
    bufferGeodesic.distances = [ distance ];
    bufferGeodesic.outSpatialReference = app.map.spatialReference;
    bufferGeodesic.unit = unit;
    bufferGeodesic.geodesic = true;

    app.gsvc.buffer(bufferEuclidean, showEuclidean);
    app.gsvc.buffer(bufferGeodesic, showGeodesic);

  }

  function drawPolygon() {  
      var polygon = new esri.geometry.Polygon(distance);  
      var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol().setStyle(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID);  
      polylineGraphic = new esri.Graphic(polygon, symbol);  
      map.graphics.add(polylineGraphic);  
  }
  //The code to select features within the buffer starts here

  function doQuery() {

      var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
      query.geometry = app.bufferGeodesic.getExtent();
      layer.queryFeatures(query, queryCallback);

      var query = new esri.tasks.Query();  
      query.spatialRelationship = esri.tasks.Query.SPATIAL_REL_CONTAINS;  
      query.geometry = polylineGraphic.geometry;  
      query.returnGeometry = true;  
      qtask.execute(query, queryCallback);  
     }

  function queryCallback(featureSet) {  
      var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol();  
      app.symbol.style = esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE;  
      app.symbol.setSize(12);  
      app.symbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([255,255,0,0.5]));  

      var features = featureSet.features;  
      dojo.forEach(features, function(feature) {  
       feature.setSymbol(symbol);  
       map.graphics.add(feature);  
      });  
     }  

    dojo.addOnLoad(init); 

//The code to select features within the buffer ends here

  function showEuclidean(b) {
    var attrs, sym;

    attrs = { "type": "Euclidean" };
    sym = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol();
    sym.setColor(null);
    sym.setOutline(new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol("solid", new dojo.Color([0, 0, 255, 1]), 2));
    addGraphic(b[0], attrs, sym);
  }

  function showGeodesic(b) {
    var attrs, sym;

    attrs = { "type": "Geodesic" };
    sym = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol();
    sym.setColor(null);
    sym.setOutline(new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol("solid", new dojo.Color([255, 0, 0, 1]), 2));
    addGraphic(b[0], attrs, sym);
  }

  function addGraphic(geom, attrs, sym) {
    var template, g, s;

    template = new esri.InfoTemplate("660 Feet Buffer", "Type: ${type}");
    g = app.map.getLayer("Geodesic");
    s = app.map.getLayer("Euclidean");
    app.map.getLayer(attrs.type).add(
      new esri.Graphic(geom, sym, attrs, template)
    );

    if ( g.graphics.length > 0 &&
         s.graphics.length > 0 )  {
      app.map.setExtent(esri.graphicsExtent([g.graphics[0], s.graphics[0]]), true);
    }
  }

  function errorHandler(err) {
    console.log("error: ", err);
  }

  dojo.ready(init);



</script>
</head>

<body class="tundra">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
     data-dojo-props="design:'headline',gutters:false"
     style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">
  <div id="map"
       data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
       data-dojo-props="region:'center'">

    <div id="feedback" class="shadow">
      <h3>Geodesic Buffering</h3>
      <div id="info">
        <div id="note">
          Note:  This sample requires an ArcGIS Server version 10.1 geometry service.
        </div>
        <div id="instructions">
          Click the map to generate a line and buffer the line by 660 Feet. 
          Geodesic buffer in red, euclidean in blue. The closer the click point to the equator, 
          the more similar the results will be.

          <input type="button" value="Query for points within the polygon graphic." onclick="doQuery();" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

i removed the call below and was once again able to generate buffers.

```
dojo.addOnLoad(init)
```

afterwards, i could see that the reference to `app.bufferGeodesic` within your `doQuery()` function doesn't resolve.  which makes sense, because i don't see any mentions of it anywhere else.

i've rewritten the original sample in [AMD](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59331579/js/util_geodesic_buffering.html) and i'm going to ask the team to update it on our live website.  that being said, you're probably better off using our more modern local [geometryEngine](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ge_geodesic_buffers.html) sample as a jumping off point than this older one which relies on making a call to a geometry service.

check out this blog for more info:
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/09/23/geometryengine-part-3-overlay-analysis/